Nodemon not running: "[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart"
I have been following an online tutorial, I have verified my code with the tutorial but still not able to resolve the error. I have attached my code for reference. Please help!!!
Index.js
import app from "./server.js";
import mongodb from "mongodb";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

async function main(){
    dotenv.config();
    const client = new mongodb.MongoClient(process.env.MOVIEREVIEWS_DB_URI);
    const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
    try{
        // connect to mongodb cluster
        await client.connect();
        app.listen(port,()=>{
            console.log("server is running on port:"+port);
        });
    }
    catch(e){
        console.error(e); 
        process.exit(1);
    }
    main().catch(console.error);
}


Server.js
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import movies from './api/movies.route.js';

const app = express();

app.use(cors()); 
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/v1/movies", movies);
app.use('*', (req,res)=>{
    res.status(404).json({error: "not found"});
});

export default app;

api/movies.route.js
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router(); 
// get access to express router 
router.route('/').get((req,res) => {res.send('hello world')}); 
export default router;


Move the call to main function outside of main function. It's never getting called.
async function main(){
    dotenv.config();
    const client = new mongodb.MongoClient(process.env.MOVIEREVIEWS_DB_URI);
    const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
    try{
        // connect to mongodb cluster
        await client.connect();
        app.listen(port,()=>{
            console.log("server is running on port:"+port);
        });
    }
    catch(e){
        console.error(e); 
        process.exit(1);
    }
}
main().catch(console.error);

In your code main function never gets executed and that's why code exits.

@NeerajSahita I tried to reproduce your issue locally and my suggested solution was able to fix the problem. I suppose you removed the call instead of moving it out of function? I've updated answer to explain what I meant.

Thank you, it did resolve my error. I was encountering another error which was causing the error.
